# Compilation of Prerequisites (Signs) before Last Hour

Tags: hadith, last-day

Our Prophet (saw) often mention prerequisites (signs) before the establishment of last hour in hadiths, what is the book that compiles all those prerequisites from all authentic hadiths and has a good commentary/interpretation?

Comment: Do you mean the signs of the Hour?

Comment: @Ahmed youre right